# Index Usage in MySql InnoDb

Tags: mysql, indexing, multi-index

I wonder that the index usage in Mysql InnoDb Engine.

below is simplified example.

1. fields
   a , b , c , d
2. indexes

- a(pk)
- (a, b, d) (composite index)

3. Query
   Select ... Where a = 3 And b >= 5 And c = 4 Order by d Limit 10;

**Q.1**
in this case, how long index is used? (a , b ?) (a, b , d?)

**Q.2**
How can i optimise the index for this case?

**Q.3**
Is it okay to include a primary key (clustered index) in secondary indexes?
Or is it better to compare the primary key field at the end of the WHERE clause?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

#### Q1

Run your horses. Probably no index will be used for this query, but you can get the execution plan and verify.

#### Q2

The following index can improve performance. Again, verify the execution plan:

```
create index ix1 on t (a, c, b);
```

You can even try the "covering index":

```
create index ix1 on t (a, c, b, d);
```

For little bit of extra performance (at the cost of a heavier index).

#### Q3

In InnoDB the PK is always included in all secondary indexes. That's not the case with MyISAM, but this is not your use case.

Comment: thanks for answer. but , in my case, Order by D is not using these indexes right?

Comment: Plus,  if  InnoDB's PK is always included in all secondary indexes,  should i reorder my Where caluse like 'Where b=3 and c<3 and a=1' ?

Comment: Confirm with EXPLAIN on your query. If the result says "Using filesort" in the extra column, it is not using the index. I don't expect it to use the index in this case, because if you have an inequality condition (`>=`) the matching rows are not guaranteed to be in order to satisfy the ORDER BY.

Comment: @Bill Karwin Thanks for mentions. that query is simpleified but in real case, Too complex Where clause is used for my usecases(it is borad service and needs multiple & optional search options) is there any better plans for me?

Comment: You need to be specific about the real query to choose the best index for that query. There's no general way to make an index that will help an arbitrary query with multiple forms and optional search terms.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. how about my first comment? 'Order by D is not using these indexes right?'  -> how can i cover WHERE and ORDER BY caluse by using index?

Answer (score 0):

It is *rare* that having the PK at the beginning of a secondary index is of any use.  The one case where it *might* be useful is if *all* the columns needed by the *entire* `SELECT` are included in index.  Your example was not that case.  (Cf: "covering index")

The order of clauses `AND'd` together in `WHERE` does *not* matter.  The order of columns in an `INDEX` *does* matter.

Aside from "covering", no index will completely optimize `Where a = 3 And b >= 5 And c = 4 Order by d Limit 10`.  See [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for an algorithm for finding the optimal index.  As already suggested:  `(a,c,b)` or `(c,a,b)`.

`(a, c, b, d)` will help *only* if it is "covering".  (What is in `SELECT ...`??

`(a, b, d)` *may* run faster, but it is risky.  If the 10 desired rows are found soon, it will be fast.  But if there are not a full 10 rows in the table, it will be a slow table scan.

"Using filesort" is a consequence of `ORDER BY` and/or `GROUP BY`.  An index *may* have been useful, but the query could not have been completed using *only* the index.

Yes, the PK column(s) are always included in an InnoDB secondary key.  But they will be tacked onto the end.  Keep in mind that the order in the `INDEX` is important, and, as my cookbook indicates, `=` columns need to be listed first in the index definition.

"how can I cover WHERE and ORDER BY clause by using an index?" -- One more thing to finish answering that.  Although a "covering" index may "cover" both clauses, it can't prevent the "filesort" because of the mixture of a "range" test (`<`) and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thanks. i misunderstood that. once range query is done, cant use following indexes.

Comment: @NRALPACA - True.  Further columns in the index won't be used for filtering.  However. they can be used to achieve "covering".